# Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ is a category, is it true that if a composition $f\circ g$ of two morphisms is an epimorphism, then $f$ is an epimorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

In my "Introduction to Category Theory" class, my teacher wrote on the board something like this:

> "... due to the fact that if a composition $f\circ g$ of two morphisms is an epimorphism, then $f$ is an epimorphism...$

Honestly, I was kinda dizzy at that moment and I'm not sure If I have that part of my notes right, is that statement true? if it is, can you tell me why?

Thanks for your guidance!

Comment: Have you tried proving it? Where would you start from?

Comment: No. I'm unsure if I took that right from the board.

Comment: It takes a drawing and a few lines to check. Try! It's fun.
Start from assuming $f\circ g$ is epic and then suppose there are arrows $a,b$ such that $a \circ f = b \circ f$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$, $Y$, $Z$, and $W$ be objects of the category with arrows $f:Y\to Z$ and $g:X\to Y$.  Assume that $f\circ g$ is epi and let $h_1,h_2:Z\to W$ be arbitrary arrows such that $h_1\circ f=h_2\circ f$.  Now we have that $h_1\circ(f\circ g)=h_2\circ(f\circ g)$ by the category axioms.  As $f\circ g$ is epi we have $h_1=h_2$ by definition.  Hence $f$ is epi as desired.